# object name as string

Tags: jquery, string, object

Is there any way in jQuery to get the name of an object as a string?

i.e. if I have

```
markers.events = {
    click: function(event){},
    drag: function(event){}
};
```

I would like to get a string `"click"` or `"drag"`

Is this possible inside a `$.each(myObj, function(){})`?

I need to do the following (hopefully) on the object stated above:

```
$.each(markers.events, function(i, event){
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click/drag", event);
})
```

Comment: It is not the name of the object. It is the name of the variable. Several variables can have a reference to the same object.

Comment: Why don't you ask a question centered around what it is that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: What would you need this for?

Comment: @justkt The question you are referring is not useful. The OP of that question decided to go with object literals instead, so that question is technically unanswered.

Comment: @Sime - now that the question has been edited there is a significant difference, I agree.  It was less obvious before.

Comment: My aplogies, need to learn to slow down and explain more. ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object itself does not have a name. If you do this:

```
var x = {};
```

then an object will be created and the variable `x` will have a reference to it. However, the name of the object is not `'x'`. The object is nameless.

You can even declare another variable and set its reference to that same object:

```
var y = x;
```

Now both x and y contain a reference to the same (nameless) object.

What you want is stringify the name of a variable, based on its identifier name. That cannot be done.

---

**Update:**

The first argument of the `$.each` callback contains the name of the property:

```
$.each(markers.event, function(i, v) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, i, v);
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/SKZKv/

Comment: I've updated the question to be more relevant, can it be done from the new question?

Comment: Brilliant! I should have known really. I thought it was an integer iterator, but it's a key isn't it. Thanks v much!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `window["myObj"]` , although it only works with Global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You would do well to explain why you need this so we could help better, but you could do something like this:

```
var myVars = {
    "myVar1": "Yaay",
    "myVar2": "Yaay again"
};

for(var a in myVars){
    alert("Variable name: "+a);
}
```